# How can we apply versioning to executable/binaries in C++?

Tags: c++, cmake, binaries

I have a big C++ application which we are compiling through Jenkins and generating zipped artifacts containing binaries, headers, config and other relevant files. The build is deployed in the form of services on the client. The problem is how can apply version on those binaries to keep a tract of which build is deployed on which client?

Like with earlier C# application we used make changes to AssemblyVersion file with the tags that we apply on GIT and then compile and we could see the executable have the version applied. Is there a way to do the same in C++?

We are using CMakeLists.txt file for generating builds. We have linux based environment (CentOS 7.5) the application is developed in C++.

Thanks in advances!

Comment: For which platform?

Comment: If it's Windows, update the relevant string(s) in the `VERSIONINFO` section of your resource file before compilation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's linux based platform and C++ application

Comment: Linux doesn't really support full version information in executables, your best option is probably just to generate a header file with the version in a constant then compile that into your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using CMake, what you can do is use the [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/configure_file.html) function in your CMakeLists.txt to create a C++ source file which includes your Git version information as a string, then include the created file into your target.

You can get the Git version information into a CMake variable by calling the git executable from CMake, although there are [prewritten modules](https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules/blob/master/GetGitRevisionDescription.cmake) out there to do the heavy lifting.

You can then use the command-line `strings` and `grep` tools to find the version string in the binary, or some other method to get it programmatically, depending on if you're making an executable or library.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. That will be great if there is a working example. I know it's a lot to ask for but I am newbie, your help will be highly appreciated.